# c# textbox number format without lose its first value

Tags: c#, formatting, textbox, numbers

I have winform Project that have textboxes. I will use these textboxes for mathematical operations. In textboxes I want to display numbers without dot. For-ex;

number : 123.384243333333333;

display format : 123

So i used codes below.

```
string result = (height * rate).ToString();
textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", result);
```

But math calculations must be presize. If i want to reach textbox value

```
string Width= textbox1.Text;
```

Width value will be 123. But i want to reach the first value which is 123.384243333333333.
So after formatting result loses its precision. How can i keep first value?

I used tag property for another actions. So i can not use.

DataGirdView control gives us this opportunity with cellformatting event. Cell displays value without dot, but cell keeps the real(first) value. I am searching something like that.

Comment: Utilizize classes.

Comment: step 1) _keep all numeric values numeric!_ don't turn anything you want to process later into a string, use strings _only_ for output. step 2) you're done.

Comment: @zaggler Do you mean adding new property to textbox? If so how?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann could u be more specific? I changed "result" variable from string to double but it is not worked. 'double result = (height * rate);'                                            't.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", result);'

Comment: i don't see how i could. use _only numbers_ for calculation. use strings _only_ for display. _do not_ use values from strings to calculate anything.

Comment: Derive a new class from `TextBox`, add a decimal property to keep the value, in the setter of the new property truncate the value to get the integral part and set it to the `Text` property. `Text = Math.Truncate(value).ToString();`.

Comment: @dr.null thanx for attention. Could you share any link with an example of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NumericUpDown**

The [`NumericUpDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=net-5.0) is supposed to be the default choice for this problem where you can keep the real value and control what to display. In your case, set the [`DecimalPlaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.decimalplaces?view=net-5.0) property to `0` (the default value) and set the [`Minimum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum?view=net-5.0) and [`Maximum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum?view=net-5.0) properties to the [`Decimal.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.minvalue?view=net-5.0) and [`Decimal.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.maxvalue?view=net-5.0) respectively.

```cs
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
            
    numericUpDown1.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
    numericUpDown1.Minimum = decimal.MinValue;
    numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 0; // Default...

    // The same for the other numeric controls...
}
```

Or, subclass to set the default values:

```cs
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public MyNumericUpDown()
    {
        Minimum = decimal.MinValue;
        Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="NumericUpDown.Minimum"/>
    [DefaultValue(typeof(decimal), "-79228162514264337593543950335")]
    public new decimal Minimum { get => base.Minimum; set => base.Minimum = value; }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="NumericUpDown.Maximum"/>
    [DefaultValue(typeof(decimal), "79228162514264337593543950335")]
    public new decimal Maximum { get => base.Maximum; set => base.Maximum = value; }
}
```

[image: SOQ68431065A]

---

**TextBox**

If the spin box is not an option and you need to use a `TextBox`. Create a new class and inherit the `TextBox` control, add a decimal property to store the real value and use it's setter to assign the integral part of the value to the `Text` property. Also you need to override the `OnValidating` method to validate the inputs as shown below if you allow text edit/paste.

```cs
[DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class IntTextBox : TextBox
{
    public IntTextBox() : base()
    {
        //Comment if you allow text edit/paste...
        ReadOnly = true;
        BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    }

    private decimal _value;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(decimal), "0")]
    public decimal Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                Text = Math.Truncate(value).ToString();
                OnValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValidating(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnValidating(e);

        if (ReadOnly) return;
        // Change as required...
        if (Text.Trim().Length == 0) Value = 0;
        else if (decimal.TryParse(Text, out var res))
        {
            if (res % 1 != 0 && res != _value) Value = res;
            else if (res != Math.Truncate(_value)) Value = res;
        }
        else
            Text = Math.Truncate(Value).ToString();
    }

    // Handle this in the host instead of the TextChanged event if you need so...
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e) =>
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

[image: SOQ68431065B]

Using this custom `TextBox`, forget the `Text` property and use instead the `Value` property to set/get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Initial values in "Tag" property of your textbox and use from it as actual value:

```
 
double result = height * rate;
textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", result.ToString());
textbox1.Tag = result;
//...
double actualValue = double.Parse(textbox1.Tag.ToString());
```

Comment: thanx for your time and attention. But in explanation i wrote i used tag property for different purpose.